# Probability of Drawing Two Aces Conditioned on Drawing One Being Ace of Spades

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, conditional-probability

I am studying probability and came up upon something that I couldn't understand.

The problems is to calculate the probability of getting two aces, given that one of the two cards drawn is the ace of spades. I know that we need to calculate the intersection of the probability of the two events and divide that by the probability of getting the ace of spades. Now the answer that is provided is this:

$$\dfrac{2\times \frac{1\times 3}{52\times 51}}{\frac{1*\binom{51}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}}=\frac{1}{17}$$

I understand the denominator part. Where we choose first choose the ace of spade, then choose any of the 51 cards and divide that by all possible outcomes (52C2).

However, what I do not understand is why is the numerator multiplied by two. I reckon that the probability of getting the ace of spade and another ace should be just 1/52 multiplied by 3/51

$$\frac{1}{52} \times \frac{3}{51}$$

Why do we multiply by two?

Thank you

Comment: Because the ace of spades could be first card or second card: $\frac{1}{52} \times \frac{3}{51}+\frac{3}{52} \times \frac{1}{51}$

Comment: @DanielMathias That kinda makes since but doesn't the way we pick mean that order doesn't matter?

Comment: $2\times \frac{1\times 3}{52\times 51}=\frac{1\times 3}{\binom{52}{2}}$

Comment: The title asks for the intersection of two *numbers*, which is meaningless. Please edit the title so it means what you actually want it to mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done :)

Comment: @Daniel Mathias okay the second notation clarifies it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if I write your solution like this, it will be more clear:

$$\cfrac{\binom{2}{1} \cdot \cfrac{1}{52} \cdot \cfrac{3}{51}}{\cfrac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{51}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}} = \cfrac{1}{17}$$

There are two ways to draw one ace of spades when drawing two cards: either you draw the ace of spade first, or you draw it second. Thus, $\binom{2}{1}$.

Comment: How would you write the numerator in combinatorics terms?

Comment: Well, you choose one ace of spades, of which there is $1$, and one ace of not-spades, of which there are $3$, and the total number of ways to draw two cards from $52$ is $\binom{52}{2}$ So $\cfrac{\binom{1}{1} \cdot \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}$

Comment: thats perfect! You see like this it makes sense. I think the gap in my understanding was the fact that by definition, doing 1/52 * 3/51 gives us one of the two correct pairs only, while the combinatorics notations you showed gives accounts for their being two pairs.